# Extract required data with details from SQL data table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have below data in SQL Database

```
Path
------------
Mb\Dbi\Abc
Mb\Dbi\Abc\123
Mb\Dbi\Dks
Mb\Dbi\Abc\Hig
Mb\Dbi\Abc\123\Xyz
Mb\Dbi\Abc
Mb\Dbi\Abc\Hig
Mb\Dbi\Abc\123
Mb\Dbi\Hig
Mb\Dbi\Dks\67H
```

I want to extract the above data in below format, Here "Mb\Dbi" remains constant and need to extract distinct Names after that and also need their exact value path.

```
Sr.       Name           Value
1     Abc           Mb\Dbi\Abc
2     Abc\123       Mb\Dbi\Abc\123
3     Dks           Mb\Dbi\Dks
4     Abc\Hig       Mb\Dbi\Abc\Hig
5     Abc\123\Xyz   Mb\DbiAbc\123\Xyz
6     Dks\67H       Mb\Dbi\Dks\67H
```

What will be the query/stored procedure /function to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You also want to generate the Serial Number:

```
SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [Path]))   AS [Sr.]
       ,REPLACE ([Path],'Mb\Dbi','')            AS [Name]}
       ,[Path]                                  AS [Value]}
FROM  tbl_PathValues
```

Or you can have the target table with a column predefined as an Identity column.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified what database server you are using.

Either way, you need to search for a replace function.

In SQL Server, the function is replace, you can find the definition here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms186862(v=sql.105).aspx

Your query will look like this in SQL Server:

```
Select replace(subquery.path,'Mb\Dbi','') AS Name, subquery.path as Value from (Select distinct path from {yourtable}) subquery
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked perfectly. Also I have mentioned the DB as SQL in question header itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT RIGHT(Value, (SELECT LENGTH(Value) - 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this,

```
SELECT RIGHT(DB.Path,SELECT LENGTH(DB.Path) - 6) AS 'Name', DB.Path AS 'Value' FROM DB;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert your data into Database by escaping '\'. Further following query will solve your problem:

Solution is for MySQL

```
SELECT  @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS 'Sr.',SUBSTRING(path, 8) AS `name`, path AS VALUE FROM test_path, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r;
```

Hope it helps...